# DB2/JAVA: dbjcc doesn't detect parameter marker at my SQL

Tags: java, db2

I'm using Java against a DB2 database and I'm having this error message:

```
 Error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10448][12695][4.19.66]  Invalid argument: Parameter marker ':machineIdsParam' was not present in the SQL String ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
```

with the code here below:

```
        String ENABLED_NAMED_PARAMS_YES = "1";
        int DB2_DRIVER_TYPE = 4;
        
        Properties properties = new Properties(); // Create Properties object
        properties.put("user", config.getDbUser());         // Set user ID for connection
        properties.put("password", config.getDbPassword());     // Set password for connection
        properties.put("enableNamedParameterMarkers", ENABLED_NAMED_PARAMS_YES);
        properties.put("driverType", DB2_DRIVER_TYPE);
        // Load the driver
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        
        //Establish connection          
        DB2Connection currentConnection = (DB2Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(config.getDbUrl(), properties);
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("WITH mymachines AS (SELECT machineId");
        sb.append(" FROM XMLTABLE('for $id in tokenize($s, \",\") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' ");
        sb.append(" PASSING CAST (:machineIdsParam AS VARCHAR (100)) AS \"s\" COLUMNS");
        sb.append(" machineId INT PATH '.')) ");
        sb.append(" SELECT machineId from mymachines ");
        String sqlString = sb.toString();
        
        String machineIds = "930,603";  // This is an input I receive as a parameter;
        DB2PreparedStatement ps = (DB2PreparedStatement) currentConnection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
        
        ps.setJccStringAtName(":machineIdsParam", machineIds);
        
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.toString());
        }
```

The strange thing is that this is code working in another Java class and I can't find the difference other than the very SQL string, which is somehow different, except for the XML table part. I suspect something is going on with the db2 driver for Java.

**Additional data**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
        <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
        <version>4.19.66</version>
    </dependency>
```

IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ: **4.19.66**

SELECT VERSIONNUMBER FROM SYSIBM.SYSVERSIONS

| VERSIONNUMBER |
| --- |
| -10050900 |
| 9070900 |
| 10050800 |
| 10051000 |
| 11010405 |
| 11010406 |
| 11050700 |

Answer (score 1):

Wrong parameter name reference in the `setJccXXXAtName` method.
Try:
`ps.setJccStringAtName("machineIdsParam", machineIds);`
instead of:
`ps.setJccStringAtName(":machineIdsParam", machineIds);`